# understanding opencv remap parameters

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

The opencv remap function should map positions from 1 position to another. However I cannot quite figure out how to make these calls.

```
    Mat base1(Mat base) {
        std::vector<float> vec;
        for (int x = 0; x < base.cols; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < base.rows; y++) {
                vec.push_back(y * base.cols + x);
            }
        }
        return Mat(vec);
    }

    Mat base2(Mat base) {
        std::vector<float> vec;
        for (int x = 0; x < base.cols; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < base.rows; y++) {
                vec.push_back((y * base.cols + x+1)%(base.cols*base.rows+base.cols));
            }
        }
        return Mat(vec);
    }
 Mat remap(Mat input) {


    Mat r;
    remap(input, r, base1(input), base2(input),  0, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar());


return ret;
}
```

should result in a image that is shifted 1 pixel to the right right? Instead it seems to get stuck in some kind of infinite loop where the program doesn't respond to anything any more.

Looking through the documentation again it seems like each the two arrays have some kind of relation to x and y not to origin and target. But how do you use 2 arrays for that, would't you need a 2d array for that rather then just 2 arrays? Or is there something else going on entirely?